# how to svn update when I have svn deleted local files?

Tags: svn

Using svn I have a branch checked out. In my local copy I deleted some files with svn delete.

In the meantime, some other files were modified and checked in to the repository. I want to update my local copy with those changes. I normally do this with svn update and the result has always been, that the files I changed stay the same, while the files others have changed in the meantime, are updated.

I expect the same would happen if I delete files that nobody else touched - they stay deleted, while other files update.

But I get:

```
svn update
```

(...)

```
svn: Can't open file (...) No such file or directory
```

and svn exits immediately with failure status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen a similar issue to this before and I think it is to do with the file you deleted having changes that needed to be applied before your delete could happen.

The SVN client *should* be smarter and just ignore the changes, but apparently it isn't.

To fix it I had to:

1. Restore the relevant file(s)
2. Perform the update
3. Deal with conflicts, if any
4. Re-delete the file
5. Update/commit

Comment: Well my question was incorrect, I did not expect the files to be changed that I deleted, and they should not be, but... somebody messed up and they did erroneously change such a file, and that created the problem.